# Is the tower property true conditional on vector?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, iterated-integrals

Let $X|\theta \sim F$ with $\theta$ a random vector and $X$ a random variable. Is it true that
$$
E[X] = E[E[X|\theta]]
$$
even though $\theta$ is a vector? If so, can one say that if $X|\mu,\sigma \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then $E[X] = E[E[X|\mu,\sigma]] = E[\mu]$?

Comment: Yes, and yes. Both are correct.

Comment: Random vectors are *vector-valued random variables*.  So the tower property is applicable.

Comment: The tower property is a property of measures as opposed the random objects (which by definition, are functions living in the underlying measure space). So, tower property holds for any random object, not only random variables or random vectors. For example, you can use it with a random set $\omega \mapsto S(\omega) \subset \mathbf{R}^2,$ and a random variable from sets to numbers $X(S),$ for instance Poisson process in 2-dimensions. In this case, $X(S) \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\text{area}(S))$ and therefore $E(X) = E(E(X\mid S)) = E(S).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @geetha290krm mentioned, it is true.